# Uniqueness of projection in a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $M$ be a subspace of $X$ and $x \in X$ be any vector in $X$. Consider $\displaystyle \hat{x}_M=\arg \inf_{m\in M}\|x - m\|$. Under what conditions for $l_p$ norms $p = 1,...,\infty$ is $\hat{x}_M$ unique? Assume that solutions to this infimization problem exist.

Note: Uniqueness may not be possible for all $l_p$ norms. I am aware about counter examples in $l_\infty$ but would like to know counter examples as well as restrictions under which uniqueness would prevail in other $l_p$ norms.

Comment: What does arg mean?

Comment: arg stands for argument. In this context it means that $\hat{x}_M$ is the vector in $M$ closest to $x$ in the corresponding $l_p$ norm sense(i.e., $\hat{x}_M$ minimizes $\|x-m\|$ over entire $M$).

Comment: In your general set-up with $X$ a Banach space, the conditions you list aren't enough to guarantee that such a point even exists, even when $M$ is closed. For example, in the space of continuous functions on $[-1,1]$ with the $L^1$-norm, consider the subspace $M$ of functions for which $f(0) = 1$. There is no point of $M$ that is closest to zero. So it would make sense to state at the outset in your question what kind of space you're talking about.

Comment: Ok! Restrict to cases where there is a solution to the minimization problem. Through this question my aim is to make understand under what conditions there would be uniqueness of projections in Banach spaces. So please assume that in this problem solutions exist to the infimization problem.

Comment: @user180040 your counter-example does not work, the space you describe is not a Banach space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions are unique if the norm of the Banach space is strictly convex:
$$
\|\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\| = \lambda \|x\|+ (1-\lambda)\|y\|
$$
only if $x=y$ or $\lambda\in\{0,1\}$. Or equivalently,
$$
\|\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\| < \lambda \|x\|+ (1-\lambda)\|y\|
$$
for all $x\ne y$, $\lambda\in(0,1)$.

Now assume that the norm is strictly convex. 
This implies for $x\ne y$
$$
\|\frac12x + \frac12y\| < \frac12\|x\|+\frac12\|y\|.
$$
Take minimizers $x_1,x_2$ of the distance. Assume $x_1\ne x_2$. 
Then by strict convexity
$$
\|\frac12(x_1+x_2)-x\|=\|\frac12(x_1-x) + \frac12(x_2-x)\| < \frac12\|x_1-x\|+\frac12\|x_2-x\| = \inf_{\hat x\in M}\|\hat x-x\|.
$$
This is a contradiction and the minimizers are unique. Hence projection is unique in $l^p$, $1<p<\infty$.

The solution need not to be unique in $l^1$: The counterexample works in $\mathbb R^2$ with $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm, it can be extended to $l^1$.

Set $x=(1,1)^T$, $M = \mathrm{span}((1,-1)^T)$. Set $x_1=(0,0)^T$, $x_2 = (-1,1)^T$.
Then
$$
\|x-x_1\|_1 = 2 = \|x-x_2\|_1.
$$
By convexity of the norm, it follows that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are minizers. Hence the projection is not unique in $l^1$.

Comment: Could you clarify your definition of strictly convex norm? It seems to me that all norms satisfy the condition you mentioned for strict convexity of the norm.

Comment: Added the definition of strictly convex. Norms are convex, but not necessarily strictly convex. $l^1$ and $l^\infty$ type norms are not strictly convex.